# Android ContentProvider applyBatch not saving all contact data

Tags: java, android, save, contacts

Im trying to save a contact with data in all available fields.
But for some reason not all the data gets saved.
Only fields that seem to work are:

- StructuredName
- Phone
- Im
- Organization

Can anyone give me an idea of where my mistake lies?

```
public void saveContact(Context context) 
    {       
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> op_list = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

        op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                .build());

        op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
        .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, "Dislayname")
        .withValue(StructuredName.PREFIX, "Prefix")
        .withValue(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, "First")
        .withValue(StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, "Last")
        .withValue(StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME, "Middle")
        .withValue(StructuredName.SUFFIX, "Suffix")
        .build());

        op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                  .withValue(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                  .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Nickname.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                  .withValue(Nickname.NAME, "Nickname")
                  .withValue(Nickname.TYPE, Nickname.TYPE_SHORT_NAME)
                  .build());

        op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                 .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)                        
                 .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                 .withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_WORK)
                 .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, "66666666")
                 .withValue(Phone.LABEL, "")
                 .build());

        op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                 .withValue(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                 .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                 .withValue(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_WORK)
                 .withValue(Email.DATA, "test@test.com")
                 .build());

        op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                 .withValue(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                 .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Website.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                 .withValue(Website.TYPE, Website.TYPE_WORK)
                 .withValue(Website.URL, "www.site.com")
                 .build());

        op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                 .withValue(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(StructuredPostal.TYPE, StructuredPostal.TYPE_HOME)
                .withValue(StructuredPostal.STREET, "TEST STREET")
                .withValue(StructuredPostal.CITY, "TEST CITY")
                .withValue(StructuredPostal.REGION, "TEST REGION")
                .withValue(StructuredPostal.POSTCODE, "00000")
                .withValue(StructuredPostal.COUNTRY, "TEST COUNTRY")
                .withValue(StructuredPostal.NEIGHBORHOOD, "TEST NEIGHBORHOOD")
                .withValue(StructuredPostal.POBOX, "TEST POBOX")
                .build());

        op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE )
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY, "Company")
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE, "Job Title")
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.JOB_DESCRIPTION, "Job description/position")
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.DEPARTMENT, "Department")
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.OFFICE_LOCATION, "Office location")
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.SYMBOL, "Symbol")
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.PHONETIC_NAME, "Phonetic name")
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE_WORK)
                .build());

        op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation
                  .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                  .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                  .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                  .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.DATA, "skype@a.com")
                  .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.TYPE, Im.TYPE_WORK)
                  .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.PROTOCOL, Im.PROTOCOL_SKYPE)
                  .build());

        op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                  .withValue(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                  .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Nickname.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                  .withValue(Note.NOTE, "Note")
                  .build());

        op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                  .withValue(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                  .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                  .withValue(android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE, "2013-06-06")
                  .withValue(android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE, android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY)
                  .withValue(android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.LABEL, "Birthday")
                  .build());

        op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                  .withValue(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                  .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Relation.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                  .withValue(Relation.NAME, "Relation name")
                  .withValue(Relation.TYPE, Relation.TYPE_BROTHER)
                  .build());

        try {
            context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, op_list);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d("contacts", "saveContact", e);
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually just a tiny but important typo! You use `withValueBackreference()` only for those types which function - you use `withValue()` for those others. No wonder, those do not work. Just use `withValueBackReference()` here as well and all will work as expected!

Comment: argh i cant believe i missed that.. doh!
thank you very much! :)

Comment: Don't woory. Stuff like this happens all the time. And it costs us way too much time too find it :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is an [impeccable explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655291/semantics-of-withvaluebackreference) about `withValueBackreference` and `withValue`.