# What is the point of ContentResolver.bulkInsert(..)?

Tags: android

**My goal**

I want to insert multiple records into sqlite in batches (transactionally).

**My question**

I found the method `android.content.ContentResolver`.[bulkInsert](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/content/ContentResolver.java;hb=HEAD#l650)(..) interesting but the javadoc states:

> This function make no guarantees about the atomicity of the insertions.

Why would android provide a method that is crippled ? Can you name me usecases for non-atomic insertions ? I am going to obviously going to override `ContentProvider.bulkInsert(..)` to ensure atomicity myself so I'm not sure why it is phrase like this.

Answer (score 4):

We need to override the bulk insert method like following...

```
public class Provider extends ContentProvider {
    public static final Uri URI = Uri.parse("content://com.example.android.hoge/");
    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        Helper helper = Helper.getInstance(getContext(), null);
        SQLiteDatabase sdb = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sdb.query(
                Table.TABLENAME,
                new String[]{Table.ID, Table.DATA, Table.CREATED},
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null,
                null,
                sortOrder,
                null
        );
        return cursor;
    }
    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        Helper helper = Helper.getInstance(getContext(), null);
        SQLiteDatabase sdb = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        sdb.insert(Table.TABLENAME, null, values);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return uri;
    }

    /**
     * super.bulkInsert is implemented the loop of insert without transaction
     * So we need to override it and implement transaction.
     */
    @Override
    public int bulkInsert(Uri uri, ContentValues[] values) {
        Helper helper = Helper.getInstance(getContext(), null);
        SQLiteDatabase sdb = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        sdb.beginTransaction();
        SQLiteStatement stmt = sdb.compileStatement(
            "INSERT INTO `" + Table.TABLENAME + "`(`" + Table.DATA + "`, `" + Table.CREATED + "`) VALUES (?, ?);"
        );
        int length = values.length;
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            stmt.bindString(1, values[i].getAsString(Table.DATA));
            stmt.bindLong(2, values[i].getAsLong(Table.CREATED));
            stmt.executeInsert();
        }
        sdb.setTransactionSuccessful();
        sdb.endTransaction();
        return length;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        Helper helper = Helper.getInstance(getContext(), null);
        SQLiteDatabase sdb = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        int rows = sdb.update(Table.TABLENAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return rows;
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        Helper helper = Helper.getInstance(getContext(), null);
        SQLiteDatabase sdb = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        int rows = sdb.delete(Table.TABLENAME, selection, selectionArgs);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return rows;
    }

    private static class Helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        static Helper INSTANCE = null;
        private Helper(Context context, CursorFactory factory) {
            super(context, Table.FILENAME, factory, Table.VERSION);
        }
        public static Helper getInstance(Context context, CursorFactory factory) {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = new Helper(context, factory);
            }
            return INSTANCE;
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(
                "CREATE TABLE `" + Table.TABLENAME + "`(" +
                " `" + Table.ID      + "` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                " `" + Table.CREATED + "` INTEGER," +
                " `" + Table.DATA    + "` TEXT" +
                ");"
            );
        }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You really need to do your transactions in `try`/`catch` blocks or your transaction may never _end_.

Answer (score 2):

Use applyBatch() instead.

This allows you to perform many different operations in a transactional manner, however there is a performance hit for this fexibility.

The relevant documentation can be found here in the [ContentResolver SDK documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#applyBatch%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.content.ContentProviderOperation%3E%29)

I have provided a quick tutorial on using applybatch in [the symantics of backReferences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4655291/808940)

I also recommend looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2231318/808940) which discusses overriding applyBatch

Answer (score 1):

> This function make no guarantees about the atomicity of the
>   insertions.

Correct me if I'm wrong but this is because we have no idea whether the given content provider overrides the `bulkInsert()` method unless it is our own provider. If the bulkInsert() method is not overriden, default implementation will iterate over the values and call `insert(Uri, ContentValues)` on each of them. It should be fine if you are using your own provider and know that you have implemented the `bulkInsert()` method like following example and use the `endTransaction()` method in finally block:

```
    @Override
    public int bulkInsert(Uri uri, ContentValues[] values) {
        final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        switch (match) {
            case WEATHER:
                db.beginTransaction();
                int returnCount = 0;
                try {
                    for (ContentValues value : values) {
                        normalizeDate(value);
                        long _id = db.insert(WeatherEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                                null, value);
                        if (_id != -1) {
                            returnCount++;
                        }
                    }
                    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                } finally {
                    db.endTransaction();
                }
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
                return returnCount;
            default:
                return super.bulkInsert(uri, values);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First Add method for bulk insert in your content provider

```
 @Override
public int bulkInsert(@NonNull Uri uri, @NonNull ContentValues[] values) {
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case USERS:
            for (ContentValues value : values) {
                long rowID = sqLiteDatabase.insert(YOUR_TABLENAME, "", value);
                if (rowID > 0) {
                    Uri _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, rowID);  //append ID into CONTENT_URI
                    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri, null);
                    return values.length;    //return total number of data inserted
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    return super.bulkInsert(uri, values);
}
```

Add below code in button click (Below is executed to insert bulk data)

```
            String userName = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
            String userCity = editTextUserCity.getText().toString();

            Log.d("BulkInsert", "onClick: -------START------");
            ContentValues[] contentValue = new ContentValues[5000];
            for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {

                contentValue[i] = new ContentValues();  // initialize Array of content values

                //store data in content values object
                contentValue[i].put(UserModel.USER_CITY, userCity);
                contentValue[i].put(UserModel.USER_NAME, userName);
                contentValue[i].put(UserModel.USER_PINCODE, userPincode);
            }
            int count = getContentResolver().bulkInsert(YOUR_TABLE_URI, contentValue);   //insert data
            Log.d("BulkInsert", "onClick: " + count);  //Display number of data inserted
            Log.d("BulkInsert", "onClick: -------STOP------");
```

Comment: for me its giving innovation target exception