# Is ContentResolver#bulkInsert faster than doing ContentResolver#insert one by one?

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

Based on the description of `bulkInsert` [1], it says:

```
 This function make no guarantees about the atomicity of the insertions.
```

I think what it actually does it, inserting rows one-by-one. Here comes the question: does it really improves performance, compared to calling `insert` [2] one-by-one, since they are actually doing the same thing?

[1] [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#bulkInsert(android.net.Uri,%20android.content.ContentValues[])](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#bulkInsert(android.net.Uri,%20android.content.ContentValues%5B%5D))

[2] https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#insert(android.net.Uri,%20android.content.ContentValues)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming its not a custom content provider that overrides the bulkInsert method there is no difference.

Where the difference comes is when its a custom provider where bulkInsert is overridden and a transaction is created which will perform better than doing regular insert

See:
[What is the point of ContentResolver.bulkInsert(..)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725593/what-is-the-point-of-contentresolver-bulkinsert)

Comment: bulkInsert saves Interprocess Communications (IPC) and only occupies only one thread. Does this make any difference?

Comment: For example, my code calls ContentResolver N times if I want to insert using `insert`, whereas only one time if I use `bulkInsert`;