# Android: how can I lock SQLite database accessible with ContentProvider (or other way of executing atomic conditional operations)

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, android-contentprovider, atomic

I got two tables in my SQLite DB: `entities` and `user_actions`. Their approximate schemes:

[image]

The flow of the program is something like this (all DB accesses handled by ContentProvider):

1. The user performs some action which modifies one of the entities
2. The corresponding entity is updated in `entities` immediately. `locally_modified` value of this entity is set to `1`
3. The information about user's action is stored in `user_actions`
4. At some point in future a sync session with the server is being initiated (I use [SyncAdapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html) framework)
5. User's actions from `user_actions` are uploaded to the server one by one and removed from the DB in a background thread
6. When the uploading completed, I need to clear `locally_modified` flags in `entities`

At this point I encounter my atomicity issue: the synchronization with the server happens in a background thread, therefore the user can use the app and perform additional actions. As a consequence, right before I clear `locally_modified` flag for an entity, I must check that there are no records in `user_actions` corresponding to this entity. These three steps must be executed atomically for each entity having `locally_modified` set to `1`:

1. Query `user_actions` for entries corresponding to entity's `_id`
2. Test whether the query from #1 returned an empty set
3. Clear `locally_modified` of that entity to `0`

Given the above scenario, I have three questions:

**Q1:** Is there a way to lock SQLite DB accessed over ContentProvider in Android such that it can be accessed only by the locking thread?

**Q2:** If the answer to Q1 is positive, what happens if some other thread tries to access a locked DB? What precautions should I take to ensure reliable operation?

**Q3:** It is possible to execute atomic transactions with conditional logic using [ContentProviderOperation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProviderOperation.html)? You can use "back-references" as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6741039/2463035) and [this blog post](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/androids-contentprovideroperation-withbackreference-explained/) to reference the result of a previous operations, but is there a way to use that result in some kind of `if-else` statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be pretty simple, but it is kind of a "hack" - just add additional `Uri` to `ContentProvider`.

For example: initially my `ContentProvider` supported the following URIs:

- `Uri.withAppendedPath(MyContract.CONTENT_URI, "entities")`
- `Uri.withAppendedPath(MyContract.CONTENT_URI, "user_actions")`

In order to support the atomic operation described in the question I added an additional `Uri`:

- `Uri.withAppendedPath(MyContract.CONTENT_URI, "clear_modified_flag")`

When this `Uri` is updated through:

```
getContentResolver().update(
    MyContract.ClearModifiedFlag.CONTENT_URI,
    new ContentValues(),
    null,
    null);
```

my `ContentProvider` executes an SQLite `transaction` that locks the database for the duration of the operation and rolls it back in case of any errors (as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8163179/2463035)).

That's it.

P.S. my `ContentProvider` is not exported (i.e. other apps can't access and use it), therefore it is safe to add this new `Uri` to it. But keep in mind that if you do export your `ContentProvider`, then exposing functionality like this one could be problematic.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to lock SQLite DB in Android such that it can be accessed only by the locking thread?

Yes, have a look at `SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction()` ([source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java#SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction%28%29)). I believe you need [SQLite's exclusive transactions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html), but you need to study that a bit more for your exact usage.

> If the answer to Q1 is positive, what happens if some other thread tries to access a locked DB? What precautions should I take to ensure reliable operation?

There's an `SQLite.amIInTransaction()` method that you could check, or just catch an `SQLiteDatabaseLockedException` ([more SQLite exceptions that you should look up](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteException.html))

> It is possible to execute atomic transactions with conditional logic using ContentProviderOperation? You can use "back-references" as described in this answer and this blog post to reference the result of a previous operations, but is there a way to use that result in some kind of if-else statement?

Never done that, but it seems that overriding ContentProvider's applyBatch and wrapping it in a transaction should work:

[Android: SQLite transactions when using ContentResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231318/android-sqlite-transactions-when-using-contentresolver)

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I probably didn't explain myself well - I need to find a way to lock SQLite DB which is accessed through ContentProvider. My third question was inspired by the thread you linked, and just wrapping `applyBatch()` in transaction is not enough...