# Android Retrofit + ProgressDialog freezing while getting big data

Tags: android, retrofit, android-contentprovider, retrofit2

I have created one api which has 100k+ records. I have done my job to get data in chunks of 10 thousands records per request.

As per Logical part If I get **flag = true** It will send request again.

**CODE:**

Created ProgressDialog:

```
/**
 * First Sync Progressbar
 */
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(NavigationActivity.this);
progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait...");
progressDialog.setMessage("Synchronizing...");
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

**First Sync Function:**

```
private void doFirstSync(final String authToken) {
    try {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (progressDialog != null && !progressDialog.isShowing())
                    progressDialog.show();
            }
        });

        Cursor tableCursor = getContentResolver().query(KOOPSContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_TABLES, null, null, null, null);

        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

        if (tableCursor != null) {

            JSONObject object = new JSONObject();

            if (tableCursor.getCount() > 0) {
                while (tableCursor.moveToNext()) {

                    object.put(TTables.TABLE_NAME,
                            tableCursor.getString(tableCursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_NAME)));
                    object.put(TTables.TABLE_UTP,
                            tableCursor.isNull(tableCursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_UTP)) ? ""
                                    : tableCursor.getString(tableCursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_UTP)));
                    object.put(TTables.TABLE_LAST_ID,
                            tableCursor.isNull(tableCursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_LAST_ID)) ? ""
                                    : tableCursor.getString(tableCursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_LAST_ID)));

                    array.put(object);
                    object = new JSONObject();
                }
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "Array of Table : " + array.toString());

            tableCursor.close();
        }

        firstSyncCall = retrofitInterfaces.firstSync(authToken, array.toString(), KOOPS.getDeviceId(getApplicationContext()));
        firstSyncCall.enqueue(new MyCallback<FirstSync>(NavigationActivity.this) {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final FirstSync firstSync) {

                boolean isSendAgain = firstSync.getFlag();

                /**
                 * Start Time
                 */
                long lStartTime = new Date().getTime();

                /**
                 *
                 * Getting Tables Array and based on this will
                 * get data from all tables
                 *
                 */
                List<Table> tables = firstSync.getTables();

                /**** FIRST SYNC ****/
                for (int tableIndex = 0; tableIndex < tables.size(); tableIndex++) {

                    String tableName = tables.get(tableIndex).getName();
                    String tableUTP = tables.get(tableIndex).getUtp();
                    int tableLastID = tables.get(tableIndex).getLastId();

                    switch (tableName) {
                        case TProductCategory.TABLE_PRODUCT_CATEGORY:
                            /** Product Category **/
                            List<ProductCategory> productCategory = firstSync.getData().getProductCategory();

                            int productCategorySize = productCategory.size();
                            Log.d(TAG, "Product Category Size : " + productCategorySize);
                            if (productCategorySize > 0) {
                                ContentValues[] productCategoryContentValues = new ContentValues[productCategorySize];
                                for (int pIndex = 0; pIndex < productCategorySize; pIndex++) {
                                    productCategoryContentValues[pIndex] = productCategory.get(pIndex).getContentValues();
                                }
                                getContentResolver().bulkInsert(KOOPSContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_PRODUCT_CATEGORY, productCategoryContentValues);
                                Log.d(TAG, "Product Category Inserted..." + productCategorySize);
                            }
                            break;
                        case TProduct.TABLE_PRODUCT:
                            /**
                             * Product Insert
                             */
                            List<Product> products = firstSync.getData().getProduct();
                            int productSize = products.size();
                            Log.d(TAG, "Product Size : " + productSize);
                            if (productSize > 0) {
                                ContentValues[] productContentValues = new ContentValues[productSize];
                                for (int pIndex = 0; pIndex < productSize; pIndex++) {
                                    productContentValues[pIndex] = products.get(pIndex).getContentValues();
                                }
                                getContentResolver().bulkInsert(KOOPSContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_PRODUCT, productContentValues);
                                Log.d(TAG, "Product Inserted..." + productSize);
                            }
                            break;
                        case TProductUnit.TABLE_PRODUCT_UNIT:
                            /**
                             * Product Unit
                             */
                            List<ProductUnit> productUnit = firstSync.getData().getProductUnit();

                            int productUnitSize = productUnit.size();
                            Log.d(TAG, "Product Unit Size : " + productUnitSize);
                            if (productUnitSize > 0) {
                                ContentValues[] productUnitContentValues = new ContentValues[productUnitSize];
                                for (int pIndex = 0; pIndex < productUnitSize; pIndex++) {
                                    productUnitContentValues[pIndex] = productUnit.get(pIndex).getContentValues();
                                }
                                getContentResolver().bulkInsert(KOOPSContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_PRODUCT_UNIT, productUnitContentValues);
                                Log.d(TAG, "Product Unit Inserted..." + productUnitSize);
                            }
                            break;
                        case TProductImage.TABLE_PRODUCT_IMAGE:
                            /**
                             * Product Image Insert
                             */
                            List<ProductImage> productsImages = firstSync.getData().getProductImages();
                            int productImageSize = productsImages.size();
                            Log.d(TAG, "Product Image Size : " + productImageSize);
                            if (productImageSize > 0) {
                                ContentValues[] productImageContentValues = new ContentValues[productImageSize];
                                for (int pIndex = 0; pIndex < productImageSize; pIndex++) {
                                    productImageContentValues[pIndex] = productsImages.get(pIndex).getContentValues();
                                }
                                getContentResolver().bulkInsert(KOOPSContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_PRODUCT_IMAGES, productImageContentValues);
                                Log.d(TAG, "Product Image Inserted..." + productImageSize);
                            }
                            break;
                        case TProductDescription.TABLE_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION:
                            /**
                             * Product Description Insert
                             */
                            List<ProductDescription> productDescription = firstSync.getData().getProductDescription();
                            int productDescSize = productDescription.size();
                            Log.d(TAG, "Product Desc Size : " + productDescSize);
                            if (productDescSize > 0) {
                                ContentValues[] productDescContentValues = new ContentValues[productDescSize];
                                for (int pIndex = 0; pIndex < productDescSize; pIndex++) {
                                    productDescContentValues[pIndex] = productDescription.get(pIndex).getContentValues();
                                }
                                getContentResolver().bulkInsert(KOOPSContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_PRODUCT_DESC, productDescContentValues);
                                Log.d(TAG, "Product Desc Inserted..." + productDescSize);
                            }
                            break;
                    }

                    /**
                     * Update Tables.... with UTP and Last ID
                     */
                    ContentValues tableValues = new ContentValues();

                    if (tableLastID == 0)
                        tableValues.putNull(TABLE_LAST_ID);
                    else
                        tableValues.put(TABLE_LAST_ID, tableLastID);

                    tableValues.put(TABLE_UTP, tableUTP);

                    getContentResolver().update(
                            KOOPSContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_TABLES,
                            tableValues,
                            TABLE_NAME + "=?",
                            new String[]{tableName});
                }

                long lEndTime = new Date().getTime();
                Log.d(TAG, "Taken Time : " + (lEndTime - lStartTime));

                if (isSendAgain) {
                    /**
                     * Sending Again for new Data
                     */
                    doFirstSync(authToken);
                } else {
                    /**
                     * Finally First Sync Over....
                     */
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<FirstSync> call, Throwable t) {
                super.onFailure(call, t);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailed(Call<FirstSync> call, Response<FirstSync> response) {
                super.onFailed(call, response);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGE("Error First Sync : " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

**RetrofitService:**

```
public class RetrofitClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "my_url....";

    /**
     * Get Retrofit with config of Interceptor
     */
    public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

        if(Log.isLoggable(LogUtils.TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();

            // set your desired log level
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

            // add logging as last interceptor
            httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
        }

        httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request original = chain.request();
                HttpUrl originalHttpUrl = original.url();

                HttpUrl url = originalHttpUrl.newBuilder()
                        .addQueryParameter("request_from", "custAppAnd")
                        .build();

                // Request customization: add request headers
                Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                        .url(url);

                Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });

        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Get API Service
     *
     * @return API Service
     */
    public static RetrofitInterfaces getApiService() {
        return getRetrofit().create(RetrofitInterfaces.class);
    }
}
```

[image]

My JSON  Example:

```
{
  "data": {
    "product_category": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Category 1",
        "priority": 0,
        "is_saleable": 0,
        "is_purchasable": 0,
        "status": 0,
        "itp": "2016-09-20 14:55:55",
        "utp": "2016-09-21 12:22:53"
      }
    ],
    "product_unit": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Liter",
        "status": 0,
        "itp": "2015-03-23 16:44:28",
        "utp": "2015-12-15 18:23:50"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Kilogram",
        "status": 0,
        "itp": "2015-03-23 16:46:04",
        "utp": "2015-12-15 18:23:44"
      }
    ],
    "product": [
      {
        "id": 96,
        "name": "Product 96",
        "code": "PRO 96",
        "product_category_id": 4,
        "product_unit_id": 4,
        "priority": 0,
        "is_saleable": 0,
        "is_purchasable": 0,
        "is_new": 0,
        "status": 0,
        "itp": "2016-09-21 11:09:28",
        "utp": "2016-09-21 11:09:28",
        "rate": "25.00",
        "discount": "2.00",
        "offer_discount": "10.00"
      }
    ]
  },
  "tables": [
    {
      "name": "product_category",
      "utp": "2016-09-29 10:09:51",
      "last_id": 200
    },
    {
      "name": "product_unit",
      "utp": "2016-09-29 10:09:51",
      "last_id": 7
    },
    {
      "name": "product",
      "utp": "2016-09-29 10:09:52",
      "last_id": 236
    },
    {
      "name": "product_image",
      "utp": "2016-09-29 10:09:53",
      "last_id": 9688
    }
  ],
  "flag": true
}
```

**QUESTIONS:**

1. Its freezing ProgerssBar while loading/getting/inserting data.
2. Is there any other best way to bulk insert using ContentProvider*because its also takes 150 seconds to insert 10000 records?

Comment: `SQLTransaction` is useful for inserting Bulk records at once

Comment: @MD How can I do it with ContentProvider? as Content Provider provides bulkInsert method, will it not be useful?

Comment: obviosuly because `doFirstSync` is called on UI thread ...

Comment: But I am doing whole process in Asynchronous Task of Retrofit. @Selvin

Comment: @PratikButani No It's useful but I guess try SQLTransaction  at least once. It's very easy to implement

Comment: @PratikButani whole process? what about iterating the cursor?

Comment: @MD Any link which can help me to create custom query in Content Providers.

Comment: Also without measuring where exactly app is freezing it is hard to say...

Comment: I think big data is problem, @Selvin How much records can we get at a time in one request?

Comment: another problem is ... inserting/updating to provider may cause reloading data somewhere (fx if you are using Loaders API) - you need to check all registerd observers

Comment: @PratikButani I don't think Retrofit cause problem. The hang problem reaised becoz after getting all the records (10k) you can process that one by one so it will take much CPU for sql operation

Comment: implement doFirstSync() inside a async task

Comment: @Selvin Is there any example or link to do this.

Comment: yes, there are plenty, mostly can be obtained via google search(no, I do not have one ready to paste, and i have no time for google 'em)

Comment: @Selvin Sure. Thanks :)

Comment: @MD What can I do for that?

Comment: @PratikButani I am not sure but you can try this way. After getting response separate your task in different thread. I mean once you get response do SQL insert operation in bulk and in separate thread each time. You can refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231318/android-sqlite-transactions-when-using-contentresolver) and [this](https://eshyu.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/using-sqlite-transactions-with-your-contentprovider/) for `(SQLTraction + Contentprovider)`

Comment: @RissmonSuresh Asynchronous Task is already doing with Retrofit enqueue method.

Comment: @MD Thank you so much :) Second links is really helpful to me.

Comment: @PratikButan I think now you got way how to handle ?

Comment: Yes, Finally I will do like, First *Array Creation* process will be do in thread and inner process of success callback also in thread. @MD

Comment: @PratikButani Great